# How to Fetch Tab label from from PermissionSetTabSetting Object

Tags: soql

I need to fetch details of all Tabs from salesforce org and need to check permissions available to respective profiles for these Tabs.

I am performing SOQL query like following

```
select Id,Name, ParentId, Parent.ProfileId, Visibility from PermissionSetTabSetting
```

Which is returning me Name of tab like,
for Standard it will be Standard : standard-Chatter and for custom tab it is returning me API name of custom object.
[image]

I wanted to check how I can get label of Tab , like if I do SOQL on `AppTabMember` object, I get following details.
[image]

How I can get label of Tab using `PermissionSetTabSetting` object.

Answer (score 0):

According to the fields available within `PermissionSetTabSetting`, this isn't possible.  Even if you started the query on the Parent `PermissionSet`, the tab label isn't accessible.

I think two SOQL queries are the only way to go.

Reference: [PermissionSet Metadata Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm)